# Having trouble with lining up block elements after making them inline

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

I am trying to line up this paragraph without the navigation menu going out of whack and the logo not being in place. I tried making everything inline however I had no luck. Next I tried to use the float property and that just made things worse. I've searched W3C and Codecademy and still haven't managed to get anything.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!-- BACKGROUND -->
<body id = "background">

<!-- PASTICCERIA ITALIA -->
<!-- <a id = "logo" href = "home.html"> <img src = "images/logo.png"> </a> -->


<!-- NAVIGATION LINKS-->
<!-- <div id = "navibar">
    <nav>

        <a class = "navibar" href = "aboutthebakery.html"> ABOUT THE BAKERY </a>

        <a class = "navibar" href = "bakeryselection.html"> BAKERY SELECTION </a>

        <a class = "navibar" href = "viewthemenu.html"> VIEW THE MENU </a>

        <a class = "navibar" href = "visitalocation.html"> VISIT A LOCATION </a>

        <a class = "navibar" href = "http://example.com/--.html"> WEDDINGS & OCCASIONS </a>

        <a class = "navibar" href = "http://example.com/--.html"> CATERING 
        </a>

    </nav>
</div> -->

<h2 id = "about_heading"> ABOUT THE BAKERY </h2>    

<img id = "greenbar1" alt = "greenbar1" src = "images/greenbar1.png"> 

<div id = "about_paragraph">

    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor... </p>

</div> 

<img id = "greenbar2" alt = "greenbar2" src = "images/greenbar2.png">

<h3 id = "meet_heading"> MEET OUR TEAM </h3>
```

HERE IS THE CSS:

```
/* BACKGROUND */
#background {

    background-margin-top: 0%;
    background-margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;

    background-image: url("images/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-color: #fffee3;
}

#logo {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
nav {
    list-style: none;

    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;

    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
}

/* NAVIGATION DIV CONTAINING LINKS */
#navibar {
    text-align: center;

    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-right: 48%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 8%;
}

.navibar {
    display: block;

    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;

    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;

    color: #000000;

    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana; 
}

.navibar:hover {
    color: #c92727;

    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Verdana; 
}

/* ABOUT THE BAKERY */
#about_heading {
    text-align: center;

    font-family: Georgia;

    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}

#greenbar1 {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 50%;
}

#about_paragraph {
    text-align: justify;

    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;

    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 22%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 42%;

    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
}

#greenbar2 {
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 55%;
}

#meet_heading {
    text-align: center;

    font-family: Georgia;

    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

To make it work:

1) I tried removing margin-right and margin-bottom from #navibar
2) added a float: left to #navibar.
3) I enclosed all the content within 'content' div as shown:

```
<div class="content">
<h2 id = "about_heading"> ABOUT THE BAKERY </h2>    
<img id = "greenbar1" alt = "greenbar1" src = "images/greenbar1.png"> 
<div id = "about_paragraph">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor... </p>
</div> 
<img id = "greenbar2" alt = "greenbar2" src = "images/greenbar2.png">
<h3 id = "meet_heading"> MEET OUR TEAM </h3>
</div>
```

4) I added in the css

```
.content {float: right;width: 70%;}
```

Updated:
Please find the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/33bb7/

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your suggestions however that did not work as well. I am really stumped here as I tried running it through W3C Validator and didn't get an answer either.